# Why doesn't changing a macro (#define) in a header file require a new build?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I'm somewhat new to **C** and just discovered something interesting.  I changed the value of a simple macro that was #defined in a header file

```
#define MRB 1000
```

to

```
#define MRB 100
```

and when I ran make again, it said there were no changes ("nothing to be done for 'all'").
 How exactly do macros work such that they don't need to be part of a build?

Comment: It sounds like your build system didn't pick up on the fact that the file was changed...

Comment: What development environment is this?

Comment: gcc compiler, building as c99 (run from the command line, not from an IDE)

Comment: I guess the macro is in a .h file and there is no reference to that file in the makefile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has a lot more to do with how make works than how macros work.  If it doesn't require a rebuild, then you have specified your dependencies incorrectly.  Read up on `makedepend`.

Comment: The header file isn't mentioned in the Makefile, but it's included in .c files that are.  Are dependencies not inferred then based on the files that are made?

Comment: @shelman, not at all.  All make knows is what you tell it in the build rules.  You can tell make yourself about this dependency, but also there are specialized tools for determining a source file's dependencies, such as [makedepend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend).  However, even with makedepend there are dependencies that aren't described properly--the compilation flags!

Answer (score 1):

If the include file is actually used, then it should trigger a build.  If it doesn't, the dependency rules are incomplete.